# Finding Prime Number with input N in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, primes

This is a code from this link from stackexchange:
[MIPS Assembly code to find all the prime numbers below an inputted number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246994/mips-assembly-code-to-find-all-the-prime-numbers-below-an-inputted-number)

I am studying this for my exam, but how would I fix this code to make it so that it prints out prime numbers from 2-N

As the post in the link, I was able to complete step two from the answer but am currently having difficultly implementing step 1 in the code

Here are the two problem that occur in the code:
There are two problems:

1. When you increment i you forget to set j back to 2. L3 should be moved 1 line 
   up. (difficulty implementing this)
2. ble in MIPS is less than or equal to, so your code is actually checking j <= 
   i, not j < i. This causes your code to check i % j when i = j, which always 
   has a remainder 0 and will register as not prime. Changing 'ble' to 'blt' 
   should fix this. Same goes for the i < n check.

Here is the code:

```
# The number is read through the keyboard 
.text
.globl main

 main:
 # Display message to user for a number
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, prompt1
 syscall

 # read keyboard into $v0 (number x is upper bound number to find primes)
 li $v0, 5 
 syscall

 # move the number from $v0 to $t0
 move $t0, $v0 # $t0 = n

 # store 2 in $t1 and $t2
 li $t1, 2 # i
 li $t2, 2 # j

 L3: # for (int i=2; i<n; i++)
 # store 0 in $t3
 li $t3, 0 # p = 0;

 L2: # for (int j=2; j<i; j++)
 # do div of two numbers
 div $t2, $t1

 # store the remainder in $t4
 mfhi $t4

 # branch if remainder is not 0 to L1
 bne $t4, 0, L1 # if (i % j == 0)

 # set $t3 as 1
 li $t3, 1 # p = 1

 # if p=1 break to next i
 beq $t3, 1, L4

 L1: # if (i % j == 0)
 # add 1 to t2
 addi $t2, $t2, 1 # j++

 # repeat code while j < i
 ble $t2, $t1, L2

 # print integer function call 1 
 # put the answer into $a0
 li $v0, 1 
 move $a0, $t1
 syscall # System.out.println(i)
 #print comma
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, comma
 syscall

 L4:
 # add 1 to t1
 addi $t1, $t1, 1 # i++

 # repeat code while i < n
 ble $t1, $t0, L3 # for (int i=2; i<n; i++)

 .data
 prompt1:
 .asciiz "Enter a number "
 comma:
 .asciiz ","
```

Thanks in advance :]

Comment: It literally tells you to move `L3` one line up, what problem are you having with that? Well, okay, make that two because empty lines don't count :)

Comment: I did that but still outputs same values, but the problem with me is how do i set j to be 2 when I is incremented?    addu $t2 , $zero, 2 in L4?

Comment: By making `li $t2, 2` part of the loop, by putting the `L3` label before that instruction instead of after.

Comment: L3: # for (int i=2; i<n; i++)
      # store 0 in $t3
      li $t2, 2
      li $t3, 0 # p = 0;

Comment: when doing that the output does not change as it still print out 2~n and not primes of 2~n